# Pass specific converters/templates to template with jsViews/jsRender

Tags: templates, jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to pass in converters and/or templates only to a specific template. According to [the API](http://www.jsviews.com/#tmplrender) you can only pass in *helpers*, but not converters or templates.

Is there any way to do this or does someone know if it is planned to support this in the future?

**Note** Passing them in globally via `$.views.templates({...})` or `$.views.converters({...})` is not really an option, because I will have way to many and perhaps even name-conflicting templates and converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare converters with your templates - and they will be private to the template. See [Registering templates: $.templates()](http://www.jsviews.com/#d.templates). Look for *"Advanced scenarios: Associating private resources with templates"*.

In addition, [the API for registering converters](http://www.jsviews.com/#converters): `$.views.converters({...})` also allows you to register a converter (or a set of converters) either globally, or locally just for a specific template. See the section *"Adding converters as private resources for a parent template"*. To make them local, or private, to a template, just pass in the template as last parameter in your converters() call.

So here is a template with its own special converter declared along with the template:

```
$.templates({
  myTemplate: {
    markup: "Use my converter {{myconv:name}}",
    converters: {
      myconv: function(val) { return myCalculatedValue; }
    }
  }
});
```

Now `{{myconv:...}}` is specific to `myTemplate` and won't be available elsewhere.

Now suppose I want to dynamically replace the "myconv", still just within `myTemplate`. I can add/change it at any time using the `converters()` API:

```
$.views.converters(
  "myconv",
  function(val) { return myNewUpdatedCalculatedValue; },
  $.templates.myTemplate // Only override it for myTemplate, not globally...
);
```

Here are some related links:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/converters
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/form-els/converters
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/hover (This one declares a 'private' converter)

Comment: Amazing! I was looking at the completely wrong spot, I assumed it would be similar to the Helpers in the `link(selector, helpers)` or `render(helpers)` style.
Maybe you can make this a little more obvious in the documentation?
Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @mrs_sheep: Local converters now override global converters of the same name.